# Dynamic js loading based on page url

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to load page specific javascript based in the url of the page.

Before I was loading a page like this:

```
<script src = "src/home.js"></script>
```

Now, I want to load the script tag only if the user is in the home page:

```
 let url = window.location.pathname;
 if (url == "/home") { //Home page
     let script = document.createElement('script');
      script.src = "src/home.js";
  }
```

But the home page script is not loading.

Comment: _"But the home page script is not loading"_ . Please confirm it in your network console

Comment: Yes the file is not in network js files but I can see my other js files that are not page specific

Comment: Can you `alert(url)` and see what its value is when you are on home page?